# Weird kids' keyhole popup book?

Tags: identification-request

There was a book when I was a kid that I had. It must have been an early 2000s or a 90s book. It was about looking through this keyhole. I remember one page being peeking through the blinds to see outside. The last page was a pull out pop up with a keyhole cut out. You could see several different rooms through this layered keyhole, like a boy picking his nose or an old lady and that. Its art style was wacky and strange and the book cover was a watercolor grey with a keyhole or something.

Comment: Could this be _Peepo!_ (a.k.a. _Peek-A-Boo!_) by Janet and Allan Ahlberg, as shown on https://medium.com/wonderbly-backstage/the-janet-and-alan-ahlberg-product-portfolio-teardown-58d0f6faa9af  ?

Comment: I’m looking for this too and can’t think of what it is! Did you ever find it?

Answer (score 3):

*The Snoops* by Miriam Moss perhaps.

The back cover has a keyhole image: [image: back cover]

From the [Publishers Weekly review](https://www.publishersweekly.com/9780525459729):

> Readers get the scoop through the eyes of the Snoops, until the
> binoculars are turned on the last page, which offers a 3-D peek into
> number nine Keyhole Place. There readers can spy the Snoops
> themselves, picking their noses, practicing karaoke and snarfing
> chocolates while clad only in underwear. Moss's (Jigsaw) text creates
> a hushed, conspiratorial tone and creepily paranoid atmosphere.
> Spidery, crudely rendered hand-lettered text sets off the eccentric
> style of French artist Durand's cartoon illustrations, often framed by
> a keyhole, raised blinds or a binocular shape.

Amazon [reviewer](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R29450IQMCQ62S/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=184011004X) mentions accordion-style pop up at the end.